# Python Error - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

I am a week into learning Python following 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' and am trying to run this web scraper program but am receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PythonProjects/webscaperprice.py", line 13, in <module>
    price = getEbayPrice('http://www.ebay.com/itm/401911857365?epid=1274633325&hash=item5d93d040d5:g:Ox8AAOSwERFdmKB4')
  File "F:/PythonProjects/webscaperprice.py", line 9, in getEbayPrice
    return elems[0].text()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

```
import bs4, requests

def getEbayPrice(productURL):
    res = requests.get(productURL)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#prcIsum')
    return elems[0].text()

price = getEbayPrice('https://www.ebay.com/itm/401911857365?epid=1274633325&hash=item5d93d040d5:g:Ox8AAOSwERFdmKB4')  
print('The price is ' + price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need `return elems[0].text`, as "text" here points to a string directly and not a method to get the text.

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up putting return elems[0].text.split() and it seemed to work. I still don't fully understand how.

Comment: You need to define whether you want a string or a list ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ If you split a text without specifying anything, it returns a list containing that text. `"abc".split() == ["abc"]`.